# Use malloc to define a string address

Tags: c, file, malloc

I get no output when I run this code. I'm expecting the file to be written to with uppercase values and also uppercase values to be printed to the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    FILE *fP;
    
    char *str = "this is an example";
    /* Im not sure if this line is right */
    str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    
    fopen("4.txt", "w");

    size_t length = strlen(str);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        /* This line fails */
        fprintf(fP, "%c", toupper(*(str +i )));
        printf("%c", toupper(*(str +i )));
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try: `fP = fopen("4.txt", "w");`... And, you should be checking `if( fP == NULL ) /* error and exit */` AND, don't forget to `fclose( fP );` when your done using it... PS: There's no need for `malloc()` in this code... In fact, reassigning pointer `str` to uninitialise memory will end in tears...

Comment: As I've commented before, read the warnings. Any decent modern compiler should be telling you that fP is not initialized.

Comment: If you are trying to make str into a 100-byte array, then just declare it as a 100-byte array.

Answer (score 4):

You are running fopen() without it returning to fp, This will just open the file stream but not let it be referred to with fp, You need to change that line to

```
fp = fopen("4.txt" , "w");
```

check if fopen failed by checking if fp is storing a NULL address

```
if(!fp){
   printf("fopen() failed");
   return -1;
}
```

Also, you are running strlen() on str but since you allocated memory without storing anything in it (the string allocated earlier was overwritten because you wrote a new value to str, that value being the address returned by malloc) it will return a random number (malloc() gives a block of memory without clearing what was there previously, so whatever the previous program that used it put there is going to be stored in it) You need to set the string into it using strcpy() like this

```
strcpy(str , "this is an example");
```

Also, you need to free the pointer by using free() after you are done using it.

```
free(str);
```

ALWAYS free memory given by malloc() and calloc().

If you fix those issues, it should run.

Some other things to note are that main() does not appear to use command-line arguments, so the usage of

```
(int argc, const char* argv[])
```

is unnecessary in this specific sample code.

Also, the usage of

```
(*(str+i))
```

can be a bit hard to read, instead, I recommend using

```
str[i]
```

it functionally acts the same but is much easier to read

Comment: You say "the string allocated earlier was overwritten…" — not really: the pointer in `str` was changed to the value returned by `malloc()`, but the string `"this is an example"` has not been modified.

Comment: Please redo the changes I made to add capital letters and the other changes.  It's frustrating to try reading text without indicators where sentences start, etc.  And it's also frustrating to fix the problems only to see the fixups overwritten.  In English, there is not a space before a comma — please don't add them.  Space after commas — yes; spaces before — no.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I apologize for accidentally undoing your edits. I was in a bit of a rush to add more parts about proper memory management, I didn't realize that someone else was improving the grammar of the answer.

Comment: _"the string allocated earlier was overwritten"_ isn't accurate. `str` is a pointer and at first its value is the address of some storage with contents taken from `"this is an example"`. After assigning the result of `malloc` to `str` it no longer holds this address, which is to say that the address of the original storage was lost. That is, the string isn't overwritten, the pointer value is. This doesn't matter for string literals since they have static storage duration. But this does matter: if the initial allocation was dynamic this would be a memory leak.

Comment: @user17231236: worse things have happened, and it's not all that unusual, especially in the first few minutes after an answer is posted.  But it is also a good idea to keep an eye on whether anyone else has edited your answer.  Thank you for redoing the fixups.  Also: remember that if you disagree with an edit, you are at liberty to undo it.